# What causes this mouse behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What causes this to happen? (the mouse is not being moved or clicked)

[image]

Comment: I can't tell what is going on in that screenshot - it is too small

Comment: Some optical mice, on surfaces like blank sheet of paper, tend to move by themselves back and forth by a few pixels. Not sure if this is the case, but it happens.

Comment: It causes the cpu usage of Firefox to spike.  Interesting.

Comment: It happens to me too.  WinXP, Firefox 3.

Comment: heh. StackOverflow front page, if you position your mouse _just_ right....

Comment: @jjnguy SO sometimes causes my Firefox to hang for a few seconds due to CPU usage, thought it was just me, apparently not.  Like you said, interesting.

Comment: You can get it to happen in IE8 as well if you move your mouse sideways only two pixels above the top edge of one of the tabs

Answer (score 13):

I suspect that the :hover CSS style results in the object having a different size (possibly margin), which causes the :hover CSS style to cease to be applied. This returns the object to its original dimensions, and the :hover CSS style is applied by the browser once more.

The browser can only keep up with this at a certain rate and you see visible flickering.

Answer (score 8):

It's an edge condition.

Comment: isn't it called "Borderline personality" ?! :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are adding a border on hover.
But because you hover near the top, when the border is added, your cursor goes outside of the element.
Would be best to add

```
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
border-bottom: 0px;
```

to begin with, in your CSS

Comment: just realised it is actually the stack overflow website... doh! :)

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, the rollover event is adding a border which changes the effective size of the element, so that the mouse is no longer over it, or something like that...